# useRef to memoize react custom hook

Tags: reactjs

Can I use useRef() for the purpose to memoize an object from a custom hook? Because without that when if I use that returned object from the hook as a useEffect dependency I get an infinity loop of requests.

Example of my code that I use now:

```
  const apiHook = useRef({})
  apiHook.current = useRequest(
    'http://someapi',
    {
      onSuccess: (data) => {
        console.log(data)
      }
    }
  )
  useEffect(() => {
    apiHook.current.run()
  }, [])
```

Comment: i think useCallback is what you need
https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Comment: I used it but also got infinity loop of requests, maybe I used it the wrong way,  could you please share an example? with my code

Comment: i need more of your code for that, you can try like this https://andrewstevens.dev/posts/useApi-react-hook/

Comment: I use the useRequest hook from ahook package https://ahooks.js.org/hooks/async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like

```
function Component() {
  const apiResp = useRequest('http://someapi');
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`New data: ${apiResp.data}`);
  }, [apiResp.data]);
}
```

i.e. only use the *data* of the `useRequest` as a dependency.

Answer (score 1):

First params for useRequest is a function who return a promise :
() => axios(url)

Example with axios : [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-mountain-bob1m?file=/src/App.js)

Example with custom useApi : [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-framework-fjqon?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This is a good example, axios is more useful to work with requests, thank you

Comment: the two example use useRequest that allow to handle promise

Comment: my bad i dont know that useRequest can be use just like useRequest(url) ^^